# Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException (MqttAndroidClient)

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

P.S. Please read the whole question before concluding anything.

I am getting the following exception whenever connect method is called:

> Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
>   at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:146)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException
>   at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:77)
>   at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:65)
>   at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:107)

I have tried couple of code snippets but both of them are raising the same exception.

**Method 1**

```
private final String serverUri = "tcp://95.177.135.232:9001";

private void mqqtConnectAndroidClient() {
    String clientId = "clientID-" + MqttClient.generateClientId();
    mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(getMainActivity(), serverUri, clientId);
    MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mqttConnectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
    mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
    mqttConnectOptions.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
    try {
        mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                subscribeToTopic();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                AppLog.Error("Failed to connect to: " + serverUri);
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
private final String serverUri = "tcp://95.177.135.232:9001";

private void methodTwo() {
    try {
        MqttDefaultFilePersistence mdfp = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(MQTT_DIR);
        mqttClient = new MqttClient(serverUri, "1", mdfp);
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
        options.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        options.setCleanSession(true);
        mqttClient.connect(options);
        mqttClient.subscribe("#");
        mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
                AppLog.Error("Connection lost");
                try {
                    mqttClient.connect();
                } catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
                AppLog.Error("deliveryComplete");
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String arg0, MqttMessage arg1) throws Exception {
                AppLog.Error("messageArrived");
                AppLog.Error(arg1.toString());
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        AppLog.Error("Main Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Subscribe Method**

```
public void subscribeToTopic() {
    try {
        String subscriptionTopic = "#";
        mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                AppLog.Error("Subscribed!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                AppLog.Error("Failed to subscribe");
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception whilst subscribing");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I try the same server URI at [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/), It is working perfectly fine with proper connection and subscription is also giving me results. I am using the following two libraries:

> compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
>   compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'

I tried some of the SO answers likes [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258887/mqtt-on-android-connection-lost), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176056/paho-mqtt-android-connecting-to-broker-fails-with-32103?rq=1), [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799690/paho-mqtt-callbacks-in-different-classes-android-java?rq=1), [Four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791118/android-paho-mqtt-service-for-publishing?rq=1) and [Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543569/paho-mqtt-android-service-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1) but none of them are working for me.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using port 9001 and the HiveMQ Link is pointing to a MQTT over Websockets client.

You are specifying a connection URI that starts with `tcp://` which will signal to the service that it should connect with native MQTT not MQTT over Websockets.

As mentioned in the [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459142#c13) report for implementing Websocket support you need to start the connection URI with `ws://` to let the client code know to use Websockets.

Comment: Yes you're right. I tried ws:// but with web socket client and in that case it was refusing.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed issue, pls see more detail here
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/207

Interesting, but we see this even when generating unique client ids. There are multiple clients on multiple machines, so I guess there is a possibility of multiple machines generating the clientID, but down to the nanosecond is pretty unlikely for duplicate clientIds.